# Made Wordpress Plugin - Shows up at top of entire site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

****EXAM AT HIVOLDA, IN CASE EXTERNAL EXAMINER SEES THIS****

I have just made some Wordpress Plugin for school.

My PHP-files works just fine, but when I upload and activates them as plugin, they only shows up at top of the page.

As you understand, I am kinda noob...

Screenshot: s27.postimg.org/53w3bmyw3/131128oav_plugin.jpg

Here is the shortest code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registrering av åpne bakker</title>
</head>

<body>
<?PHP

/**
 * Plugin Name: Haugsdalen Skisenter Bakkeregistrering
 * Description: Registrering av åpne/stengte bakker for Haugsdalen Skisenter.
*/


function visSkjema(){   

    echo('  
    <form id="bakkerreg" name="bakkerreg" method="post" action="bakkerreg.php">
      <label for="hoved">Er hovedbakken åpen?</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="hoved" value="Åpen">Ja
      <input type="radio" name="hoved" value="Stengt">Nei<br/>
      <label for="skog1">Er skogsløypen vest åpen?</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="skog1" value="Åpen">Ja
      <input type="radio" name="skog1" value="Stengt">Nei<br/>
      <label for="skog2">Er skogsløypen øst åpen?</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="skog2" value="Åpen">Ja
      <input type="radio" name="skog2" value="Stengt">Nei<br/>  
      <input type="submit" name="lagre" id="lagre" value="Send inn">
    </form>');

}

if( isset($_POST['lagre'])) {

    if( $_POST['hoved']!="" && 
        $_POST['skog1']!="" AND  
        $_POST['skog2']!="" ){ 
    /* Her lagrer den til databasen*/

        $db = mysql_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD');
        /* Velge database */

        mysql_select_db('USERNAME',$db);
        /* Definer spørringen */

        $sql = "INSERT INTO bakker(hoved,skog1,skog2)
                VALUES('".$_POST['hoved']."',
                '".$_POST['skog1']."',
                '".$_POST['skog2']."') ";

        /* Kjør spørring */

        $resultat = mysql_query($sql);
        if($resultat) {
            echo ("<p>Grattis, du har nå registrert informasjonen!</p>");
        }else {
            echo ("<p>Du failet!</p>");
            echo ("<p>".mysql_error()."</p>");

        }
    }else{  // Manglande obligatoriske felt
        visSkjema();
    }
}else {
    /*Vis skjema, ingen har trykt på lagre knappen (enda) */
    visSkjema();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Suggestions? :)

The intention is to easy update information on the frontpage. It will be a admin-poll-system, where the company can update the information by pressing  checkboxes. I have made 3 plugins that has this function. This one has the function that the company can update which of the ski hills are open. I have also made a plugin which has a registration form, and sends to database. And a file that recieve information from the database, and admin can delete any rows.

****EXAM AT HIVOLDA, IN CASE EXTERNAL EXAMINER SEES THIS****

Comment: What do you mean "they only show up at the top of the page"? Please provide a screenshot, if possible.  Also: Make sure you're using `<?php` instead of just `<?` to open your PHP blocks.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear enough.

Here is a link to my image: (Not enough reputation to post image)
http://s27.postimg.org/53w3bmyw3/131128oav_plugin.jpg

I think this happends because I have not set the plugin to work on a set page, I have set it just to work, so it will be on all pages. Also a noob in PHP, so any suggestions would be helpful :)

Comment: So you want the form to appear on certain page(s) only?  Can you post (some of) the code that you've got, please?  (Add it to your question using the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20271401/edit).

Comment: Yes, I want it to appear on a certain page :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're a bit confused on how WordPress functions.  Plugins are all included into Wordpress at the very beginning of the page load, right after WordPress gets all its files loaded, but before it actually does anything.  This allows plugins to modify any functionality from that point further, but means you can't actually write out any code yet, because then it'd end up at the top of the page.

Wordpress combats this issue by what is called the hook system.  Hooks (or action hooks) are setup throughout WordPress and are called at certain times, and you can register your functions with them, so they are called when that hook is run.  I know that's a bit abstract, so here is an example:

```
add_action( 'get_footer', 'customplugin_footer_hook' );

function customplugin_footer_hook ($name)
{
    echo 'Some code here.';
    echo 'This will show up right before the footer, because it's registered to the get_footer action hook';
}
```

There are actions and filters, filters are designed to modify data passed to them, and return it, actions (or hooks) are designed to be given data and print something to the screen (but that isn't always what they're used for).

All this being said, it doesn't look like it'd help much with what you're actually trying to do, as processing post data in WordPress can be a bit confusing, and I can't tell if that is suppose to be a poll, or admin settings, or something else; I don't speak Norwegian :)

Give us a bit more information on what you're trying to achieve and we may be able to give you a bit more detailed information on how to do it.

Some helpful links in the meantime:

- [Wordpress action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)
- [Wordpress filter hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)
- [Decent guide over hooks](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: Thanks alot mazzzzz! You are correct, - I am confused on how WP functions/plugins works.

I will post this into my post aswell:
The intention is to easy update information on the frontpage. It will be a admin-poll-system, where the company easy can update the information just pressing  checkboxes. I have made 3 plugins that has this function. This one has the function that the company can update which of the ski hills are open. I have also made a plugin which has a registration form, and sends to database. And a file that recieve information from the database, and admin can delete any rows.

Comment: You should take a look at the Widget system in Wordpress, it sounds like what you'd be looking for.  http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/building-custom-wordpress-widgets/